# Nested Folding in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Is it possible with Notepad++ to set up folding so that it only folds a specific group? I am currently using a User Defined Language that is mostly intended for my own personal organizational purposes.

What I would like would be something like this

```
[+]Category 1<br>
[+]Category 2<br>
[-]Category 3<br>
        Item 1
        Item 2
      [-]Subgroup 1
             Item 3
      [+]Subgroup 2
[+]Category 4
```

I would like to be able to fold Subgroup 1 or 2 without closing everything below.
Specifically, I would like to be able to fold Category 3 without folding Category 4.

I am only working with plain text and using a User Defined Language to enable Code Folding. This is really only for personal purposes and doesn't need to be functional for anyone else. I just want to be able to hide the sections I need to.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was between the keyboard and the chair.

I basically just had an open bracket issue that explained my difficulty.